# error inflating class, custom view

Tags: android

I have seen this error posted before but none of the answers seem to fix my problem so I am not really sure what is going on. It is failing when it tries to inflate my class in the xml.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#EEE"
    >
    <android.view.SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </android.view.SurfaceView>
    <com.commonsware.android.picture.PictureDemo.DrawOnTop
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    </com.commonsware.android.picture.PictureDemo.DrawOnTop>
</FrameLayout>
```

Class:

```
class DrawOnTop extends View 
  { 

      public DrawOnTop(Context context) 
      { 
          super(context); 
      } 

      public DrawOnTop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
      { 
          super(context, attrs); 
      } 

      public DrawOnTop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
      { 
          super(context, attrs, defStyle); 

      } 

      @Override 
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
      { 
          Paint paint = new Paint(); 
          paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
          paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
          canvas.drawText("Test Text", 10, 10, paint); 
          canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
          super.onDraw(canvas); 
      } 
  }
```

Error:

```
02-11 16:06:25.456: E/AndroidRuntime(11717): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.commonsware.android.picture.PictureDemo.DrawOnTop
```

I have all the constructors and dont see any other problem, what am I missing?

Comment: what do you mean "It is failing when it tries to inflate my class in the xml." can you post the stack trace?

Comment: What is your package name, is it really `package com.commonsware.android.picture.PictureDemo;`?

Comment: @Sam the package is com.commonsware.android.picture ( its a series of examples from github ) The DrawOnTop class is defined in the file "PictureDemo" I was not sure if that needed to be in the xml or not but it does not work either way

Comment: Try separating DrawOnTop  to another file within the same package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try separating DrawOnTop to another file within the same package.

Comment: Could you clarify how this fixes the issue exactly? I'm getting a similar error and my class is already in its own file within the same package.

Comment: @SimonSarris Did you get the issue resolved? I am getting the same problem.

Comment: This fixes the issue because there is something wrong with how the package is being selected for inflation (via the File in question). By separating it out, you ENSURE that its in the right package because you created it, however; seems that when you import it it doesn't import the package correctly.